# ARKit navigation in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview, arkit

I would like to do ar navigation using arkit 2.0. I tried using github sample projects https://github.com/chriswang101/AR-Navigation but dont know how to pass static data of user current location and destination lat long.

From github link user search destination and then goes to ar navigation, But in my case user directly goes to ar navigation screen by using lat long of source and destination .

How can i do that. Here is what i tried so far:

```
   let l1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0987346, longitude: -117.7123592)
let l2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0990761, longitude: -117.7099627)
let l3 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0972554, longitude: -117.7093386)
let l4 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0986692, longitude: -117.7136621)
let l5 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0996506, longitude: -117.7143718)
let l6 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.1001445, longitude: -117.7129978)

let sc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0195564, longitude: -118.2889155)


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("route:::\(routeCoordinates)")

    routeCoordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.873058, longitude: 80.226391)]

    //Set to true to display an arrow which points north.
    //Checkout the comments in the property description and on the readme on this.
    //        sceneLocationView.orientToTrueNorth = false

    //        sceneLocationView.locationEstimateMethod = .coreLocationDataOnly
    sceneLocationView.showAxesNode = true
    sceneLocationView.locationDelegate = self

    if displayDebugging {
        sceneLocationView.showFeaturePoints = true
    }

    self.plotARRoute()

    view.addSubview(sceneLocationView)

    if showMapView {
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.alpha = 0.8
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        updateUserLocationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 0.5,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(ViewController.updateUserLocation),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: What's in your `self.plotARRoute()` method?

Comment: plotARroute is used to draw plolyline.. Is there any other sample code for ar nvigation except ARCL cocopod

Comment: In that github project on that method only they add lat and log. Check that method